# Prove that the series $a_n = $ $2^n \over n!$ converges to 0.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that the series $a_n = $ $2^n \over n!$ converges to 0.

I am trying to find a variable that will be bigger than $2^n\over n$ , with no luck. 
Any help, besides using binoms?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Write the terms out. The $n$th term is  bounded above by $4/n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{2^{n}}{n!} = 2\frac{2^{n-2}}{3\cdot 4 \cdots n} \leq 2\cdot \frac{2}{n} = \frac{4}{n}
$$
for all suitable $n$.

If you want $\varepsilon$-analysis: given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $n > 4/\varepsilon$ only if $4/n < \varepsilon$.

Comment: any hint on how you came to your conclusion?

Comment: $\frac{2^{n}}{n!} = 2\frac{2^{n-2}}{3\cdot 4 \cdots n} \leq \frac{4}{n}$. @YonatanIzutskiver

Answer (score 0):

Since there is already a suitable answer, I will offer another method which can be used for a large class of these sorts of problems.

Note that the Taylor series of the exponential function is given by
$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
naturally this converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and its value is $e^x$.

For all convergent series it follows that the terms of the series must converge to $0$ so $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{x^n}{n!} \right) = 0$$
Plug in $x = 2$ and the result follows.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not familiar with Taylor's theorem yet, it's a few lectures ahead of me :)

Comment: Of course! Come back to this comment once you have covered more theory about series and convergence, I am sure you will appreciate this method then!